# Discord.js 13 interaction check if interaction creator is in the guild

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I recently noticed that interactions can still be made even if a user is not in a guild this is the case in for example the server preview mode

This is causing a few issues for me

does anyone know if there is a convinient way to detect if the user who created the interaction is a guild member? Or could I block all interactions from non guild members ?

Comment: Just saying, if the person created the interaction in the guild, they're going to be in the guild. It will always return true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can search user in the guild and return if it's null.

```
var user = guild.users.cache.find(user => user.id === 'USER-ID')
if(!user) return
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Guild.members.cache.some` to determine if the user exists.

```js
const exists = interaction.guild.members.cache.some(x => x.id == interaction.user.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following piece of code:

```js
const user_exists = (<interaction>.guild.users.cache.find(user => user.id === <interaction>.user.id)) ? true : false
```

This will return true if the user exists and false if not, so you can run a check:

```js
if(!user_exists) // Tell the person they cannot run the command
```